# flutter bloc package yeild doesnot work in state management

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> While this yield in setData method doesnot work can anyone describe this?? If no parameter is sent from setData then it works. Or anyone can explain yeild how it works in bloc.

```
class LoginerrorBloc extends Bloc<LoginerrorEvent, LoginerrorState> {
  @override
  LoginerrorState get initialState => InitialLoginerrorState();

  @override
  Stream<LoginerrorState> mapEventToState(
    LoginerrorEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoginEvent) {
       yield LoginLoading();
      try {

        final url = apiUrl + 'login';
        http.Response response = await http.post(url,
            body: {'contact': event.contact, 'password': event.password});

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // var res = Authenticate.fromJson(true);
           yield* setData(Login.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)));

        } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
          var res = LoginError.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
          yield LoginErrorState(res);
        } else {
          var res = LoginError.fromJson({'message': 'Internal Server Error'});
          yield LoginErrorState(res);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        var res = NetworkError.fromJson({'message': 'Internal Server Error'});
        yield NetworkErrorState(res);
      }
    }
  }

  Stream<LoginerrorState> setData(data) async* {
          yield AuthenticateState();

  }
}
```

Comment: do you use equatable package ?

Comment: Yes. Solved this issue.

Comment: Great, could you please consider  writing an answer for your question , so it can benefit others

Comment: This is my mistake in converting object form named constructor. So i did not write answer.